# GPL-v3 using along with closed source via rest api

Tags: open-source-software, gpl

I want to use CMS distributed under GPL-v3 licenses. I am building a web application with closed code and my app invokes via REST API backend under GPL-v3. Question: is it legal to use GPL-v3 along with a client app with closed code and charge money for the app. I am not changing the code of CMS just using it as is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe should be migrated to opensource.stackexchange.com. I suspect this is already answered over there, or could be more easily there.

Comment: @Brandin We said the same thing about asking it on law LOL! IMO this is probably more of a legal question.

Comment: Maybe with a tweak to the wording (e.g. don't ask "is it legal" but ask if it is allowed by the GPL v3 license), it might be better on Open Source SE, and maybe more useful to the OP and others. Basically the question "can I do X according to open source license Y" is likely to be answered on OO SE, whereas "can I do X according to the LAW" regardless of a specific license, is probably better answered on Law SE.